# Calculate cross validation for Generalized Linear Model in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, glm, cross-validation

I am doing a regression using Generalized Linear Model.I am caught offguard using the `crossVal` function. My implementation so far;

```
x = 'Some dataset, containing the input and the output'

X = x(:,1:7);
Y = x(:,8);

cvpart = cvpartition(Y,'holdout',0.3);
Xtrain = X(training(cvpart),:);
Ytrain = Y(training(cvpart),:);
Xtest = X(test(cvpart),:);
Ytest = Y(test(cvpart),:);

mdl = GeneralizedLinearModel.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain,'linear','distr','poisson');

Ypred  = predict(mdl,Xtest);
res = (Ypred - Ytest);
RMSE_test = sqrt(mean(res.^2));
```

The code below is for calculating cross validation for mulitple regression as obtained from this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html). I want something similar for Generalized Linear Model.

```
c = cvpartition(Y,'k',10);
regf=@(Xtrain,Ytrain,Xtest)(Xtest*regress(Ytrain,Xtrain));
cvMse = crossval('mse',X,Y,'predfun',regf)
```

Comment: I want to calculate cross validation error for GLM using the functions from statistical toolbox of Matlab. Now, is there anything that I am missing, or that Matlab simply doesnot have such a function built in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either perform the cross-validation process manually (training a model for each fold, predict outcome, compute error, then report the average across all folds), or you can use the [CROSSVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html) function which wraps this whole procedure in a single call.

To give an example, I will first load and prepare a dataset (a subset of the [cars dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Auto+MPG) which ships with the Statistics Toolbox):

```
% load regression dataset
load carsmall
X = [Acceleration Cylinders Displacement Horsepower Weight];
Y = MPG;

% remove instances with missing values
missIdx = isnan(Y) | any(isnan(X),2);
X(missIdx,:) = [];
Y(missIdx) = [];

clearvars -except X Y
```

### Option 1

Here we will manually partition the data using [k-fold cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29#K-fold_cross-validation) using [cvpartition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html) (non-stratified). For each fold, we train a [GLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) model using the training data, then use the model to predict output of testing data. Next we compute and store the regression [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) for this fold. At the end, we report the average RMSE across all partitions.

```
% partition data into 10 folds
K = 10;
cv = cvpartition(numel(Y), 'kfold',K);

mse = zeros(K,1);
for k=1:K
    % training/testing indices for this fold
    trainIdx = cv.training(k);
    testIdx = cv.test(k);

    % train GLM model
    mdl = GeneralizedLinearModel.fit(X(trainIdx,:), Y(trainIdx), ...
        'linear', 'Distribution','poisson');

    % predict regression output
    Y_hat = predict(mdl, X(testIdx,:));

    % compute mean squared error
    mse(k) = mean((Y(testIdx) - Y_hat).^2);
end

% average RMSE across k-folds
avrg_rmse = mean(sqrt(mse))
```

### Option 2

Here we can simply call CROSSVAL with an appropriate function handle which computes the regression output given a set of train/test instances. See the doc page to understand the parameters.

```
% prediction function given training/testing instances
fcn = @(Xtr, Ytr, Xte) predict(...
    GeneralizedLinearModel.fit(Xtr,Ytr,'linear','distr','poisson'), ...
    Xte);

% perform cross-validation, and return average MSE across folds
mse = crossval('mse', X, Y, 'Predfun',fcn, 'kfold',10);

% compute root mean squared error
avrg_rmse = sqrt(mse)
```

You should get a similar result compared to before (slightly different of course, on account of the randomness involved in the cross-validation).

Comment: Just let me clear one thing how does the crossval function knows which part of its data is Xtr, which is Ytr. I know fcn is an anonymous function, but someone has to tell it which part of the data is which. I have gone through the doc, but this seperation of data for the anonymous function is still eluding me.

Comment: @motiur: `crossval` internally partitions the data using the same technique, then for each folds it calls the function handle passing it the appropriate training/test data sets. In fact you can tell `crossval` to use your own `cvpartition` object if you want..