# How to use `crossval` in matlab for a Leave one Out Validation method

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I have been reading the documentation: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html) but it's really unclear for me and I don't see how to use pratically `crossval` to do a leave one out cross-validation.

```
vals = crossval(fun,X)
vals = crossval(fun,X,Y,...)
mse = crossval('mse',X,y,'Predfun',predfun)
mcr = crossval('mcr',X,y,'Predfun',predfun)
val = crossval(criterion,X1,X2,...,y,'Predfun',predfun)
vals = crossval(...,'name',value)
```

I really don't understand the `fun`part.

I have estimatimate chlorophyll rate with different index. Then I have done a linear regression between those index and the field taken chlorophyll rate. Now I want to validate them, one of my estimation is a column with 22 entries, so I want to use 21 of them as trainee and 1 as a test, and do 22 loops so that all the data have been used as test. 
But I don't where should I put the regression model? If my regression is Y=aX+b,
do I re-use the a and b calculated before for the train part, or do I do a new linear regression with the train part then see what's the test will be with that? 
I am not sure I totally understood how to make a leave one out model.

Then I want to know the result of the test by calculating the RMSE (and maybe the R²).

How do I code that using `crossval`?

I saw the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093983/leave-one-out-crossvalind-in-matlab) but I don't have access to the `crossvalind` fonction with my license.

Comment: "fun is a function handle to a function with two inputs, the training subset of X, XTRAIN, and the test subset of X, XTEST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finaly figure it out: so this is my script:

First I charged my data and the linear regression fonction

```
X=indicesCha_without_Cloud(:,3);
y=Cha_g_m2t_without_Cloud(:,3);
testval=@(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST)Linear_regression_indices( XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST);
```

where in my case `fun`(in the [Mathwork help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html#zmw57dd0e186091)) is `testval`and `Linear_regression_indices` is a very simple fonction:

```
function [ Linear_regression_indices ] = Linear_regression_indices(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST )
         Linear_regression_indices=(polyval(polyfit(XTRAIN,ytrain,1),XTEST));
end
```

There is 2 ways to do it and they both give the same result:

- one by using simply the `crossval` fonction

  `cvMse = crossval('mse',X,y,'predfun',testval,'leaveout',1);`

  this will do as many fold as the data size, using each time one of the data as Xtest
- the second one is using `cvpartition`

  `c = cvpartition(n,'LeaveOut')` creates a random partition for leave-one-out cross validation on n observations. Leave-one-out is a special case of 'KFold', in which the number of folds equals the number of observations. [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html?searchHighlight=fun%20crossval)

  `c = cvpartition(y,'LeaveOut');`
  `cvMse2=crossval('mse',X,y,'predfun',testval,'partition',c);`

then the RMSE can be easily calculated

```
RMSE=sqrt(cvMse);
RMSE2=sqrt(cvMse2);
```

then I simply get my answer, in my case `RMSE=0,3548`

Comment: This link helped me a lot to understand [Calculate cross validation for Generalized Linear Model in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904179/calculate-cross-validation-for-generalized-linear-model-in-matlab) as well as [Mathwork crossvalind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) exemples. I hope it will help you as well.